# SQL Server 2012 performance degradation

Tags: sql-server, performance, sql-server-2012

We are running SQL Server 2012 SP1 on Windows Server 2012. The issue we have is that after some time the server automatically reboots.

Checking the logs did not show any errors. When looking into the SQL Server log we find these logsDate

> 24-5-2014 13:42:47
>   SQL Server is terminating because of a system shutdown. This is an informational message only. No user action is required.
>
> 24-5-2014 10:01:18
>   A significant part of sql server process memory has been paged out. This may result in a performance degradation. Duration: 14401 seconds. Working set (KB): 23684, committed (KB): 99988, memory utilization: 23%.
>
> 24-5-2014 08:01:16
>   A significant part of sql server process memory has been paged out. This may result in a performance degradation. Duration: 7200 seconds. Working set (KB): 29868, committed (KB): 99972, memory utilization: 29%.
>
> 24-5-2014 07:01:48
>   A significant part of sql server process memory has been paged out. This may result in a performance degradation. Duration: 3632 seconds. Working set (KB): 34376, committed (KB): 100004, memory utilization: 34%.

Searching the internet did not help very much. Most written about this is about server 2003.

The problem occurs frequently depending on the usage.

What steps do I need to take to fix this?

Comment: Is this a virtual or physical server? Have you configured the maximum memory setting in SQL Server?

Comment: Those small working sets - measured in MB, not GB - lead me to believe you have either (a) not given enough memory to SQL Server or (b) not given the machine itself enough memory. How much memory does the OS have? How much of that have you given to SQL Server?

Comment: The OS has 4GB. SQL has 3GB.
It is on a hosted server which is in the cloud and virtual.

Comment: Have you contacted the host/provider about this issue?

Comment: Yes, they say nothing is wrong with the hardware or virtual environment. Anything i can ask them to check?

Comment: @amaters They could check their logs to see why your machine is rebooting, for starters...

Comment: @AaronBertrand I already asked but they claim there is nothing strange. I don't know much about virtualization. Anything concrete I can tell them to look at?

Comment: Is there other software running on this box besides SQL Server that's using a lot of memory? IIS? My initial thought (why I asked if the server was virtual) was that the host could theoretically detect that the page file usage is too high and initiate a reboot. Have you tried bringing up the box, **stopping** all the SQL Server services, and seeing if the reboots still happen?

Comment: We cannot stop SQL Server. It is a production environment. The reboots even occur during night when there is 0 IIS usage

Answer (score 3):

The first message regarding the shutdown means that someone or something has initiated a shutdown of the machine. Take a look at the Windows system logs in Event Viewer for more information. You should look at log events leading up to and just after the shutdown time to look for messages indicated why Windows shutdown.

Is this a relatively newly installed server? If so, have you activated Windows? If not and you've passed the activation grace period this is one potential reason for Windows Server automatically rebooting.

Comment: It is a relatively new server. In the system logs I don't see antyhing happening.
Windows is activated when i check the computer properties window

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I found high RAM consumption from System process. So after lot of googling the answer, I found [this post](https://superuser.com/questions/645650/what-is-superfetch-and-its-relation-to-svchost-exe-localsystemnetworkrestricte) that suggests to Disable a services called Superfetch. Worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

[Enable Lock Pages In Memory](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190730.aspx) -

I would grant permissions to your SQL Engine service account. This will prevent the OS from coming and taking memory. You may also want to look at [setting your maximum allowed memory allocation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178067.aspx). Just to make sure you don't run into the opposite problem :).